# OBS Studio StreamFX cmake build missing OBS::libobs how do I connect it to this library?

Tags: linux, github, cmake, libraries, obs

I have been working on compiling from source on my linux debian computer and I can't seem to get past this one last error. I am slightly confused by how to find out where the path is looking and if anyone knows how to help I would greatly appreciate it cmake error is as follows:

```
cmake ../obs-streamfx
-- [StreamFX] This is a standalone build, please make sure you've followed the instructions.
-- [StreamFX] Version 0.12.0.191a+gd5e6399d
-- [StreamFX] The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- [StreamFX] The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- [StreamFX] Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- [StreamFX] Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- [StreamFX] Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- [StreamFX] Detecting C compile features
-- [StreamFX] Detecting C compile features - done
-- [StreamFX] Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- [StreamFX] Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- [StreamFX] Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- [StreamFX] Detecting CXX compile features
-- [StreamFX] Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- [StreamFX] Target is 64bit x86 with a pointer size of 64bit.
-- [StreamFX] Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.74.0")  
-- [StreamFX] Found FFmpeg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so (found version "56.51.100")      found components: avutil avcodec swscale 
-- [StreamFX] Found AOM: /usr/local/include   
-- Could NOT find Qt6 (missing: Qt6_DIR)
-- [StreamFX] Using Qt5.

-- [StreamFX] Applying custom flags for GCC/Clang style build.
-- [StreamFX] Targeting extended x86-64-v2.
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1670 (target_link_libraries):
 Target "StreamFX" links to:

OBS::libobs

 but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

* There is a typo in the target name.
* A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
* An ALIAS target is missing.`
```

I tried moving the source file to root to see if maybe it needed to be directly recursive to the file but it still didn't work I am fairly new but I understand most coding concepts but I can't seem to wrap my head around the "::" and what it means when it comes to where it is looking for the library.

I am using the source code from "git clone --recursive [https://github.com/Xaymar/obs-StreamFX.git"](https://github.com/Xaymar/obs-StreamFX.git%22) and I've already adjusted libobs_DIR in CMakeLists.txt to point to the file containing the proper Cmake config files which I thought might remedy but only fixed a different error I was having before.

I also tried to add an additional pathway to libobs_DIR that led directly to the libobs file folder inlcuded in the source package but that did nothing. I tried a pre-compiled plugin but it just freezes obs so this is my only option.

Comment: "I can't seem to wrap my head around the "::" and what it means ..." - This target `OBS::libobs` should be created by the [call](https://github.com/Xaymar/obs-StreamFX/blob/root/CMakeLists.txt#L669) `find_package("libobs" REQUIRED CONFIG)`, which in turn calls the script you specify in `libobs_DIR` variable. BTW, in your output I see no evidence that given `find_package` call has been executed ... so it smells like you have removed that line from `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: the find_package("libobs" REQUIRED CONFIG) still exists. I'm pointing my libobs_DIR variable poorly I think. the code I added on line 299 is as follows:" set(libobs_DIR "/home/ames/obs-streamfx/third-party/obs-studio/libobs/cmake" "/home/ames/obs-streamfx/third-party/obs-studio/UI/obs-frontend-api" CACHE PATH "Path to libobs and obs-frontend-api") " I set the pathways this way because the other errors I was getting demanded the ***Config.cmake files. this eliminated that problem but did not fix the missing obs::libobs message. should I input a different pathway? no code was removed

Comment: "the code I added on line 299 ..." - You shouldn't modify the project's files. Instead, you may set value of `libobs_DIR` variable when invoke `cmake` by using `-Dlibobs_DIR=<value>`. Note, that the variable should contain a **single path**.